# Trigger native Add Products action from Custom Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

On an Opportunity, you have the ability to Add Products to it in an Opportunity Line Item. This opens a search modal that pulls the Products in the Pricebook that you can select, then sends you to another screen to update the quantity or price or Line Description of your chosen products.

I want to call this 'Add Products' functionality from a custom lightning component.  Is there a way to do this?